# Unable to return to graphical installer during Debian Bookworm installation after switching to a virtual console

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I am trying to install Debian on a PowerEdge R830 server. Installation was going smoothly up until the moment I had to pick a mirror. I selected the top choice for mirror in Germany (in the list of German mirrors, that is the first entry in it). I got an error when the installer tried to retrieve the packages.

[image]

Since I also entered a proxy I decided to check what the output is on virtual console 4 as per instructions. From the output there I got that the mirror does not provide packages for the Debian Bookworm, which is not a big deal since I can always return and pick another one.

When trying to return to the graphical installer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I got:

[image]

All posts I was able to find talk about such an issue on an already installed system (hence the suggestions usually include `apt-get install` of some sort), which is not the case here.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems my information was outdated/incorrect.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> returns me to the graphical installer.

Answer (score 1):

The key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> allows you to switch from the graphical user interface to console `1`, also known as `TTY1` (Teletype 1).

The key combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> allow you to switch to consoles `2` to `12`.

While some of these consoles may display log information, and where some of them represents a separate virtual text console on the system where you can log in and execute commands for interacting with the system.

These consoles are also referred to as `TTY2` to `TTY12`. Typically, the graphical user interface runs on console `7` or console `1` (sometimes on console `2` or `5`).

In your case, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> will bring you back to the graphical installer.

These key combinations enable you to switch between the graphical user interface and the text-based consoles, which can be useful for performing specific tasks, troubleshooting, or accessing the console when the graphical interface is unresponsive.